# Calling BS Modal on form submission

Tags: php, bootstrap-modal

This is my page, how to get modal after form submit.

I want to get Modal as I am in requirement of doing such task. This is just simple practice modal page for my understanding.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["btn"]) && $_POST["btn"]=="Submit")
    {
      ?>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(window).load(function()
      {
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
      });
        </script>
      <?php
    }
    ?> 

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container">
      <h2>Modal Example</h2>

     <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>   -->
         <form method="post">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" name="text" class="form-control">  <br>
                <input type="submit" name="btn" class="btn btn-danger">
                 </div>
         </form>
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">


 <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Could you not use "event.preventDefault()" on form submission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all do not include `<script>` tags outside the html tags, put them in the `<body>` or `<head>` tags. Whenever you are working with the DOM and jQuery, wrap your code in a [document ready closure](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/). Ex:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank You so much for providing necessary detail. My code is working properly in the manner which I wanted. Now I am looking forward to implement it in my project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your jQuery after the definition of the modal in the HTML Since you can not display a BS modal before the HTML page and the modal is defined.

Also the POST response from the form submit button is "Submit Query" not just "Submit".

Put the following PHP under the last `</div>` tag from the modal definition and the before the `</body>` tag and it will work:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST["btn"]) && $_POST["btn"]=="Submit Query")
    {
        ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            </script>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: thanks for response. but it is actually not working for me. please can you suggest any other method ?

Comment: Please see my edit. you need to also remove the IF-section and put the jQuery in the HTML code. It will work then.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry It was my mistake. As you suggested now it is working. Thanks.  But there is only one problem that modal is not holding for long time and it gets vanish just as submission. Can you please further tell me how can I hold this modal or should I have to use AJAX call for this ?

Comment: Sorry, but I misunderstood your intention. I will update my answer with the new solution.

Comment: Yes Please Help , I am in need of it badly.